# Firebase Cloud function error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is a part of the database JSON of my Angular JS webapp:

```
 users: {
   user uid (generated by push) : {
       deviceToken : "tokenID",
       name : "Display Name"
   },
   anotherUserID : {
       deviceToken : "tokenID",
       name : "Display Name"
   }
```

Below is the index JS of my cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.update = functions.database.ref('/Player')
    .onWrite(event=>{
      console.log(event.data);
      var ref = admin.database().ref('/users/'+ user.uid+ '/week1');
      ref.set(10);
      return;

    });
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: user is not defined at exports.update.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:10:49)
```

I replaced var `ref = admin.database().ref('/users/'+ user.uid+ '/week1');` with `var ref = admin.database().ref('/users/{user.uid}/week1');` and got the following error message:

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "/users/{user.uid}/week1". Paths must be non-empty strings...
```

Is there a way to access the user uid generated by the push() method within the database cloud function?

Comment: What is '/Player'? If you want to access the ID of the player within your function you could try "functions.database.ref('/Player/{playerId}')" and within your function access that ID as "const playerId = event.params.playerId;"

Comment: '/Player' is a child node in the databse. the ID i aim to access is a different child node altogether from the database node that is listened to for the onWrite function.